# Can't Import ColumnTransfomer (Scikit-Learn) - Import Error:Cannot import name 'Parallel'

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn

I use the ColumnTransfomer from Scikit-Learn and it usually works fine. Some days its decides to give me this error?

I have updated scikitlearn and it is on version 0.20. I am using Azure Notebooks (Jupyter Notebooks).

Here is the error that printed when I run:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-95a87d70dcfe> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 """
      7 
----> 8 from ._column_transformer import ColumnTransformer, make_column_transformer
      9 from ._target import TransformedTargetRegressor
     10 

~/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in <module>()
     15 
     16 from ..base import clone, TransformerMixin
---> 17 from ..utils import Parallel, delayed
     18 from ..externals import six
     19 from ..pipeline import _fit_transform_one, _transform_one, _name_estimators

ImportError: cannot import name 'Parallel'
```

Thanks!

Vrage

Comment: How have you updated the scikit learn? By pip or have you created a new anaconda environment?

Comment: Did you fix this? I got same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can import ColumnTransfomer when you are importing numpy in the start of the code. By importing with compose package, it will get solved. I did the same and it worked. Make sure you have installed all the packages properly.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
```